# Intent EditText values to another EditText values in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent

does anyone know how to pass values editText from activity 1 to editText activity 2 using intent or bundle?

[this is the first activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRslF.jpg)
[this is the second activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yh4dm.jpg)

this is the code, the EditText values from activity 1 still not showing in EditText activity 2

this is mainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val emailEt = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_email)
    val passEt = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_password)
    val nextBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.next)

    nextBtn.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
        val email = emailEt.text.toString()
        val pass = passEt.text.toString()

        intent.putExtra("email", email)
        intent.putExtra("pass", pass)
        startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

this is SecondActivity

```
class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

    val email = intent.getStringExtra("email")
    val pass = intent.getStringExtra("pass")
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this answer for help https://stackoverflow.com/a/2091482/13211263

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Comment: Show your code to get full answer

Comment: @JunaidKhalid i send my code in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Intent.putExtra()` in first activity and `getIntent().getStringExtra()` in second activity by modifying your second activity as

```
class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val emailEt = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_email)
    val passEt = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_password)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

        val email = intent.getStringExtra("email")
        val pass = intent.getStringExtra("pass")
        emailEt.setText(email)
        passEt.setText(pass)
    }
}
```

Comment: i already do that, but the EditText values from activity 1 not showing in EditText activity 2

Comment: Oh you're right! thank you so much!